# Imagebutton not showing in Android Emulator

Tags: java, android

I have a problem whose solution I am unable to find out. I am creating an imagebutton thorugh Android SDk and although it shows in Preview window it does not show in Nexus 6 Emulator. The image is attached here
[image]

Code for xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".ViewActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_bold_textsize"
    />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/rememberMe" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_g1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rad1"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rad2"
            />
    </RadioGroup>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/togb1" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Switch" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not known the diffenrence between `tools` and `android`.
`tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"` is only show on preview of IDE.
Change to
`android:src="@tools:sample/avatars"`

Check the document: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes

Comment: Sorry I just read the documentation and selected your answer as best answer but it is not working when i ran the same code what you suggested. Instead I am getting erro `  error: failed linking file resources.`. Plz help.

Comment: @AmitRay please add the log cat.

Comment: Kindly check this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E6x6bWO9xEmgzhbhvBDrSH8Q0tWfqH2V/view?usp=sharing. It has the complete logcat.

Comment: Sorry @AmitRay but `android:src` not is not working with `@tools:sample/avatars`. Please use another image in drawble or color instead of `@tools:sample/avatars`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am now using drawable folder for image but i dont understand why that same source is not accessible by android.

Answer (score 0):

Cause of, You are used `tools:src` attribute instead of `android:src`.

`tool:<attributes>` = Working only in preview emulator. It just show you Temporary hint.

`android:<attributes>` = Used for the actual definition that you have defined

for Ex. If you use `tool:text`  within textView. It's only shown like hint as how looks  applied theme.